# 403 forbidden when trying to create a bucket using Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-deployment-manager, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to create a GCS bucket using Deployment Manager using the following resource config:

```
resources:
- type: storage.v1.bucket
  name: upload-bucket
  properties:
    project: <project-id>
    name: <unique-bucket-name>
```

However, I get the following error:

```
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/the-bucket/resources/upload-bucket
  message: '{"ResourceType":"storage.v1.bucket","ResourceErrorCode":"403","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":403,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"205531008256@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
    does not have storage.buckets.get access to upload-bucket.","reason":"forbidden"}],"message":"205531008256@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
    does not have storage.buckets.get access to upload-bucket.","statusMessage":"Forbidden","requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/upload-bucket","httpMethod":"GET","suggestion":"Consider
    granting permissions to 205531008256@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com"}}'
```

The role of `205531008256@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` is `Project Editor` by default (which surely has enough permissions?), however I've also tried adding `Storage Admin` and `Project Owner` - neither seems to help.

My 2 questions are:

1. Why it is trying to use this service account?
2. How can I get Deployment Manager to be able to create a bucket?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same problem. Allow me to restate Andres S's answer more clearly.

When you wrote

```
resources:
- type: storage.v1.bucket
  name: upload-bucket
  properties:
    project: <project-id>
    name: <unique-bucket-name>
```

you probably intended create a bucket called `<unique-bucket-name>` and figured that `upload-bucket` would just be a name to refer to this bucket in the Deployment Manager. What GCP actually did was attempt to use `upload-bucket` as the actual bucket name. As far as I can tell, `<unique-bucket-name>` is never used. This caused a problem, since someone else already owns the bucket `upload-bucket`.

Comment: I recommend adding code snippet to your answer and reference it. Kudos for mentioning that Andre is correct but you don't have control over other answers. That one could get edited or deleted and then the context of your answer is broken. Make that change and @ me and I'll upvote your answer because it definitely adds clarity.

Comment: @Rodger. Done. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I recently run into similar issue, where Deployment Manager failed to create the bucket.

I have verified that:

- the permissions are not an issue as the same deployment contained other bucket that was created.
- the bucket name is not an issue as I was able to create the bucket manually.

After some googling I found there is other way to create the bucket. Instead of using `type: storage.v1.bucket` you can also use `type: gcp-types/storage-v1:buckets`.

So my final solution was to create the bucket like this:

```
- name: images-bucket
  type: gcp-types/storage-v1:buckets
  properties:
    name: images-my-project-name
    location: "eu"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I think you are specifying the name twice.

```
resources:
- type: storage.v1.bucket
  name: <unique-bucket-name>
  properties:
    project: <project-id>
```

Comment: That was what I originally tried, it gave the same error.

Comment: The code should work as it is, make sure you are using a unique bucket name, you can also try removing the project property or adding the storageclass property below the project-id in the code example [storageClass: MULTI_REGIONAL]